# Angular 8 + PrimeNG PanelMenu - how to dynamically add menu items

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-menu

Is it possible to set menu items based on data fetched from database?

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './questionnaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionnaire.component.scss'],
})
export class QuestionnaireComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Environmental',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Question 1',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 2',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 3',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
        ],
      }, {
        label: 'Social',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Question 4',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 5',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 6',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Governance',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Question 7',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 8',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
          {
            label: 'Question 9',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          }, {
            label: 'Question 10',
            icon: 'pi pi-circle-on',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

and my template:

```
<div class="questionnaire questionnaire-container">
  <div class="intro"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      PROGRESS BAR
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
      <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>
    </div>
    <div class="questionnaire-content">
      QUESTIONNAIRE CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm asking you because I don't know if its possible to do that in component, not in template where I could use *ngFor= and then generate menu items... If it's not possible, then I would find some other library for menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You will just have to use Angular's http client to request the data you want, then subscribe to it and assign the resuts to `this.items`.
The trickiest part is gonna be formatting you data from your API to a format that can be understood by PrimeNG menu panel.
In the example below I make a call to an API that returns to me a formatted items which I can assign directly to `this.items` :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("https://express-demo-feat-test2-s8pihd.herokuapp.com/api/items")
      .subscribe(data => (this.items = data as MenuItem[]));
  }
```

Here is a link to a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-panelmenu-demo-js7exc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
If you need to format your data before using it you can do something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("https://express-demo-feat-test2-s8pihd.herokuapp.com/api/items")
      .pipe(
         map(data => {
           // do some formatting
         })
      )
      .subscribe(data => (this.items = data as MenuItem[]));
  }
```

Comment: also don't forget to accept my answer if you find it helpful as people tend to forget sometimes =)